# SqlLite3 Error creating table

Tags: mysql, sqlite, delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to create tables using mysql Scripts but I'm getting errors like this:

> Exception ESQLiteNativeException in module ActivityPlan.exe at
>   0051A80E.
>
> [FireDAC][Phys][SQLite] ERROR: near "CODICE": syntax error.

```
CREATE TABLE anag_giac (CODICE char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
                        COD_TECNICO char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
                        DESCRIZION char(100) DEFAULT NULL,
                        PREZZO double DEFAULT NULL,
                        UM char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
                        STATO char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
                        KEY IANAG_GIAC (CODICE,COD_TECNICO) )
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Remove all of the `DEFAULT NULL`, to start. The default is **always** NULL unless you specify otherwise. After that, a [visit to the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) should explain the problem, particularly [foreign_key_clause](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/foreign-key-clause.html).

Comment: Just done but nothing changed!! I've got the same error

Comment: It seems a problem around the key creation..
Removing the string "KEY IANAG_GIAC (CODICE,COD_TECNICO)" it works...

Comment: Yes, as I said: see the documentation for [foreign_key_clause](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/foreign-key-clause.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE anag_giac (
  CODICE CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  COD_TECNICO CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIZION CHAR(100) NULL,
  PREZZO DOUBLE PRECISION NULL,
  UM CHAR(20) NULL,
  STATO CHAR(1) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PrimaryKey1 PRIMARY KEY (CODICE,COD_TECNICO)
);
```